# Sending multi line of body and multiple attachments

Tags: powershell

I have two different folders containing two text files, the goal is to send both txt files in an email using PowerShell. 
The first file is stored in log and the other one in Error. I found a helpful PowerShell script to do so, however I was not sure how to add both attachments in same email and in the body having two lines for each of the attachments. Below is the script, any help is appreciated:

```
# Date values to find related log file for the day and hour or the run
$y = Get-Date -format yyyy
$m = Get-Date -format MM
$d = Get-Date -format dd
$h = Get-Date -format 05
# Modify the log path
$LogPath       = "C:\Program Files\Logs\"
$LogFile       = $LogPath + "Log_" + $y + $m  + $d + "_" + $h + "*.txt" 
$LogFileName   = $LogFile | ? {Test-Path $LogFile} | Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo] }

$LogPath1       = "C:\Program Files\ERROR\"
$LogFile1       = $LogPath1 + "Log_" + $y + $m  + $d + "_" + $h + "*.txt" 
$LogFileName1   = $LogFile1 | ? {Test-Path $LogFile} | Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo] }

$MessageBodyNA = "Email from scheduler. No log file found  " + $LogFile
$MessageBodyA  = "Email from scheduler. File" + $LogFileName + " found and attached"

$MessageBodyNA1 = "Email from scheduler. No log file found " + $LogFile1
$MessageBodyA1  = "Email from scheduler. File(s) " + $LogFileName1 + " found and attached"

$FromAddress   = "test@gmail.com"

$ToAddress     = "test1@gmail.com"
$Subject       = "test"

$SMTPserver    = "SMTPServerName.com"


if ( $LogFileName | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo] })
{
  send-mailmessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -subject $Subject -body  $MessageBodyA  -smtpServer $SMTPserver -Attachments $LogFileName
}
else
{
  send-mailmessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -subject $Subject -body  $MessageBodyNA  -smtpServer $SMTPserver
}

if ( $LogFileName1 | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo] })
{
  send-mailmessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -subject $Subject -body  $MessageBodyA1  -smtpServer $SMTPserver -Attachments $LogFileName1
}
else
{
  send-mailmessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -subject $Subject -body  $MessageBodyNA1  -smtpServer $SMTPserver
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx). The `-Attachment` parameter accepts a string array, so you can attach multiple files like this:

```
Send-MailMessage -From $FromAddress -To $ToAddress -Subject $Subject `
  -Body $MessageBodyA -SmtpServer $SMTPserver `
  -Attachments $LogFileName, $logFileName1
```

A multiline body can easily be created by using a multiline string:

```
$MessageBody = @"
This is line 1.

This is line 2.
"@
```

or by concatenating multiple lines:

```
$line1 = "This is line 1."
$line2 = "This is line 2."

$MessageBody = "$line1`n`n$line2"
```

Answer (score -1):

This shows how to attach multiple files and multiple lines in mail body (please note that I didn't tested this)

```
 function sendMail{

    #SMTP server name and other mail parameters
    $smtpServer = "smtp.bethanie.com.au"
    $OFS = "`r`n`r`n"
    $a = get-date
    $SourceDir = "C:\Source\"
    $DestDir = "C:\Dest\"
    $files = get-childitem $SourceDir | where name -like "*.txt"
    $attachments = @()
    $msgFrom = "abc@abc.com"
    $msgTo = "abc@abc.com"
    $msgsubject = "Automated Task(" + $a + " )"
    $msgBody = "This is an automated mail" + $OFS + "Check the attached file"


    # Attach files of specific types 
    foreach($file in $files){
        $filename = [system.io.path]::GetFileName($file.FullName)
        $attachments += $file.fullname
    }

    Send-MailMessage -to $msgTo -From $msgFrom -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Subject $msgsubject -BodyAsHtml $msgBody -Attachments $attachments

}
#Calling function
sendMail
```

Comment: This is invalid as `-BodyAsHtml` is a switch and not a parameter that accepts a string. It should instead be used with `-Body`.